# Ayuda con vectores y numeros primos

Tags: java, java-8

`Leer 10 enteros`, almacenarlos en un arreglo y determinar en qué posición del arreglo está el mayor número primo leído.

```
        int vector[] = new int[10]; //Declaro, instancio vector
        int enteros = 0; // Variables a utilizar
        int mayor = 0;
        int indice = 0;
        int con = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) { //For que me lee el vector y me asigna el valor acada posicion.
            System.out.println("Ingrese los 10 numeros enteros: " + "Pos " + i);
            enteros = teclado.nextInt();
            vector[i] = enteros;
        }
//        vector[0] = mayor; // Igualo la posicion 0 a la vaariable
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
            if (enteros % vector[i] == 0) {
                con = con + 1;
            }
            if (con == 2 && vector[i] > mayor) {
                mayor = vector[i];
                indice = i;
            }
            con = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("El numero primo mayor esta en posicion: " + mayor);
    }
```

Comment: Buen día. Olvidaste colocar el código que tienes para que quien sepa (años no uso java y fue poco) te de sugerencias.

Comment: Intentaste realizarlo?

Comment: Si claro ya esta en descripción

Comment: Podrias aclarar cual es el problema con tu codigo? que no anda? con que parte necesitas ayuda?

Comment: Como ya doy imprimir no sale el mayor de los primos .. sale 0

Comment: debugueaste el codigo? con que cadena de 10 numeros lo probaste?

Comment: le ingrese por teclado los 10 números aleatorios

Comment: puedes subir tu codigo a algun fiddle para que lo trabajemos? como primera medida, fijate que al final del for estas haciendo con = 0; por lo tanto con nunca va a ser igual a 2. y eso lo haces en todas las vueltas

Comment: Donde validas si el número almacenado en una posición [i] es primo??

Answer (score 1):

Considero que el problema está en que te equivocaste entre el **Valor** e **Indice**, reodenando un poco el código me quedo así:

```
    int vector[] = new int[10]; //Declaro, instancio vector
    int enteros = 0; // Variables a utilizar
    int mayor = 0;
    int indice = 0;
    int con = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) { //For que me lee el vector y me asigna el valor acada posicion.
        System.out.println("Ingrese los 10 numeros enteros: " + "Pos " + i);
        enteros = teclado.nextInt();
        vector[i] = enteros;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
        if (esPrimo(vector[i])) {
            if(vector[i] > mayor){
                mayor = vector[i];
                indice = i; 
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println("El numero primo mayor esta en posicion: " + indice);
```

El codigo de la función **esPrimo(x)** sería:

```
public Boolean esPrimo(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Y funciona.